# Hyperledger fails to install on Mac 10.3 High Sierra

Tags: macos, hyperledger-fabric

I checked the minimum system (Mac OS) to install Hyperledger here:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs

However, when I attempt to install it, I use the following instructions:
https://www.permchain.de/post/setting-up-your-mac-to-use-hyperledger-fabric-2-0-and-start-your-first-network

I see the following error on my terminal that baffles me:

```
==> You are using macOS 10.13.
==> We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
```

What is the possible solution? I really want to learn Hyperledger and it is not practical no means to buy a new/latest Mac.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing looks to be from the Homebrew install script. You may need to use an alternative installation method for required tools if your Mac is not supported by Homebrew.

The system requirements you are looking at are for Hyperledger Composer, which was deprecated quite a while ago.

Look here for Hyperledger Fabric installation instructions:

- https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.4/getting_started.html
- https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.4/getting_started_run_fabric.html